# Convert Datasets to Generic List

Tags: c#, list, linq, dataset

I have a Class Properties as below

```
public class Country
{
   CountryId,
   CountryName,
   List<State>
}

Public class State
{
   StateId,
   StateName,
   List<City>
}

Public class City
{
   CityId,
   CityName
}
```

I have data set for each class which extract data from DB as below.

``````````
CountryDS  
`````````  
CountryId | CountryName
1         | India  
2         | China  

StateDS  
```````  
CountryId | StateId | StateName  
1         | 1       | UP  
1         | 2       | MP  
1         | 3       | Punjab  
2         | 10      | Beijing  

CityDS  
``````  
StateId | CityId | CityName  
1       | 1      | Agra  
1       | 2      | Mathura  
2       | 5      | Ujjain  
2       | 7      | Dewas  
3       | 10     | Amritsar
``````````

Now, I want to convert these datasets to `List<Country>` object, without nested looping or with LinQ or best way to extract data fast.

```
Country  
--> CountryId  
    CountryName  
    State  
    --> StateId  
        StateName  
        City  
        --> CityId  
            CityName
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Todays google key word is *ORM*

Comment: "without nested looping or with LinQ etc" - why to avoid them?

Comment: I have tried it with nested looping. but it takes long time to create object as i have records in millions as there can be many states in 1 country and many cities in 1 state. So i want if there is a way to do it with Linq. then help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... but it takes long time to create object as i have records in millions as there can be many states in 1 country and many cities in 1 state. So i want if there is a way to do it with Linq.

Be aware, LINQ is optimized for re-use, not for fast code. Internally LINQ will use `foreach`, which will call `GetEnumerator()` and `MoveNext()`. A `foreach` that is designed specially for your solution will probably be faster than LINQs `foreach`, and you can optimize even more by calling enumerating yourself (`GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext`).

Still, if you want to use LINQ, whenever you want objects with their sub-objects (usually with a foreign key), like Schools with their Students, Libraries with their Books, Countries with their States, [Enumerable.Groupjoin](https://www.dotnetperls.com/groupjoin) is the way to go.

So you have three collections, using primary keys and foreign kesy to point to each other:

```
IEnumerable<Country> countries = ...
IEnumerable<State> states = ...
IEnumerable<City> cities = ...
```

And you want the collection of Countries, with their States where every State has its Cities.

```
var result = countries.GroupJoin(states,  // GroupJoin countries and states
   country => country.Id,                 // from the country take the primary key
   state => state.CountryId               // from the state take the foreign key
   (country, statesOfCountry) => new      // from every country with all its states
   {                                      // make one new object
       Id = country.Id,                   // cointaining only the properties you plan to use
       Name = country.Name,
       ...

       States = ...                       // see below
   }
```

To calculate the `States of every country with their cities`, we `Groupjoin` the `statesOfCountry` collection with the `cities` collection, on matching primary and foreign key:

Continuing the LINQ above:

```
States = statesOfCountry.GroupJoin(cities,   // Groupjoin states with cities
   stateOfCountry => stateOfCountry.Id,      // from every state take the Id
   city => city.StateId,                     // from every city take the stateId
   (stateOfCountry, citiesOfState) => new    // again: when they match make a new object
   {
        // for performance: select only the properties yo actually plan to use
        Id = stateOfCountry.Id,
        Name = stateOfCountry.Name,

        // not needed: you know it equals Country.Id:
        // CountryId = stateOfCountry.CountryId,

        Cities = citiesOfState.Select(city => new
        {
             // only the properties you plan to use
             Id = city.Id,
             Name = city.Name,
             Location = city.Location,

             // not needed, you already know the value:
             // StateId = city.StateId,
        }),
   }
```

The nice thing is that you only created an enumerable object, which is: you only created something that knows how to enumerate. You didn't enumerate yet. This has the advantage that this is very fast, and if during the enumeration you decide you don't need some information you won't have to enumerate it.

For instance, once you start enumeration and you want to ignore all cities Russian cities:

```
foreach (var country in result)
{
     if (country.Name != "Russia")
        ProcessCountry(country);
     // else: ignore
```

This has the advantage that the GroupJoin of Russian cities will not be performed

Comment: So, nested foreach will work faster than linq.?
is there any other way to do the same.?

Comment: No, not per se, LINQ also uses nested foreach so that is not what makes it faster. But if you write your own code, you can do optimizations, like setting initial sizes of lists. Furthermore: LINQ will start enumerating only when you ask for elements. If you don't ask for the third element, this one won't be calculated. If you use foreach you'll have to know when to stop. If you don't know, because your caller decides when to stop, create a function that returns `IEnumerable<...>`, and use `yield return` inside your foreach. This will prevent calculating more items than callers ask for.

Comment: Ohk. Got it. Thanks for Your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Without using LinQ or nested loops you can achieve this with a small workaround.

1. Convert your DataSet to JSON.
2. Parse the JSON to appropriate Objects.

You can use newtonsoft to serialize or deserialize.

Comment: i want this object at c# as i have to do some work with this object ahead.